# MySQL Transaction giving error

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb

Been stuck on this for hours now, I am new to server development so please be easy on me.

When I try running the code below I get the following SQL error:

> Error:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
INSERT
     INTO  orders (firstname, lastname, spots, order_id)
    VALUES  ('NAME', 'NAME', 5, '20170718-FC5E8');
INSERT
     INTO  orders_info (order_id, ip, user_agent)
    VALUES  ('20170718-FC5E8', '', 'browser');
COMMIT;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'START TRANSACTION; BEGIN; INSERT INTO orders (firstname, lastname, spots, order_'` at line 1

What I am trying to do is insert data into two different tables, which I am having big trouble with. I am trying to insert data into both orders and orders_info and for doing that I am using this query code:

```
 $sql = "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; START TRANSACTION; BEGIN; INSERT INTO orders (firstname, lastname, spots, order_id)
        VALUES ('$firstname_value', '$lastname_value', $spots_value, '$unique'); INSERT INTO orders_info (order_id, ip, user_agent)
        VALUES ('$unique', '$ip', 'browser'); COMMIT;";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Your order has been placed!" ."<br><br>". "Firstname: {$firstname_value}" ."<br>". "Lastname: {$lastname_value}" ."<br>". "Spots: {$spots_value}";
            echo "<br><br>" . "ORDER #: {$unique}";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
```

Comment: for multi select depend  by the mysql driver you are using

Comment: `query` only supports 1 query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php  Be careful with this, if you get injected this function will allow for your whole DB to be manipulated or even destroyed.

Comment: Try to remove begin;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable auto commit using `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` It will automatically disabled when you use `START TRANSACTION;` and restored to original state when use `COMMIT;` In your sql commands it look like `BEGIN;` caused an issue.

So put all your sql statement in between start transaction and commit.

```
START TRANSACTION;
//your SQL statements
COMMIT;
```

Comment: `$conn->query($sql)` still wont work with this approach, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php because `Performs a query on the database`.

Comment: Hmm, how do you suggest I perform it instead?

Answer (score 1):

- Don't have multiple statements in a single call to the API.
- Then check for errors after each SQL.
- `START TRANSACTION` and `BEGIN` are synonyms; don't do both.
- `START/BEGIN` overrides `autocommit`; don't worry about `autocommit`.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, ’BEGIN’ and ‘BEGIN WORK’ are supported as aliases of ‘START TRANSACTION’. But ‘START TRANSACTION’ permits modifiers that BEGIN does not.

If AUTOCOMMIT is set to 1 (the default), then each SQL statement (within a transaction or not) is considered a complete transaction and committed by default when it finishes. When AUTOCOMMIT is set to 0, by issuing the SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 command, the subsequent series of statements acts like a transaction and no activities are committed until an explicit COMMIT statement is issued.

By default, MySQL runs with AUTOCOMMIT enabled.

Use START TRANSACTION to disable auto commit implicitly. and the auto commit will be disabled until we COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The AUTOCOMMIT mode then reverts to its previous state.